# How should I model these relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a **post** model. Each post has a *title* and many **snippets**.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :snippets
end

class Snippet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  attr_accessible :position, :post_id
end
```

I want to have 4 **different types** of snippet i.e.:

- body (text)
- image (string)
- code (text)
- video (string)

## Q1

Should I create four new models (called text, code, video and image) which extend the snippet model like so?:

```
class Text < Snipppet
  attr_accessible :body
end

class Image < Snippet
  attr_accessible :image
end

class Video < Snippet
  attr_accessible :title
end

class Code < Snippet
  attr_accessible code
end
```

## Q2

How can I refer to the content of each snippet in my view when each snippet can be one of 4 different things?

In my view I'd like to put something like this:

```
- for snippet in @post.snippets
  = place the content of the snippet here
```

## Q3

I don't think it sounds like a good idea to have a "type" field on the snippet model as this would possibly lead to strong coupling of the database and the code. Is there some kind of rails magic that will help me out in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks to everyone who answered, but I think I've managed to fix this by using jystewart's rails 3 version of the [acts_as_polymorphs gem](https://github.com/jystewart/has_many_polymorphs)

**Here's what I did:**

So let's recall, we have **Posts** and we have four different types of **snippet**. So that's 6 different models (post.rb, snippet.rb, code.rb. text.rb, image.rb and video.rb)

- Posts have many snippets.
- Snippets belong to posts.
- Code, text, video and image are all types of snippet

And the big problem is that we don't know what type of object a snippet is, because it can be one of 4 different things.

At first, I tried to do this with Single Table Inheritance, but the objects (code, text, video and image) are, in my opinion, too different from one another for this to work well and I didn't like the fact that it would likely result in lots of empty database cells so I went along the Polymorphic route.

I couldn't get standard polymorphic associations to work here because this is not your usual polymorphic situation. Normally, when dealing with polymorphism, we're talking about something like a comments model, which can attach to multiple other models. The polymorphic entity is always the same thing. But in this case, we're talking about snippets model which can be one of 4 different things. This is not a simple belongs_to situation. Polymorphism was not happening.

Then I stumbled upon this article by [m.onkey.org](http://m.onkey.org/has_many_polymorphs-for-dummies) - which is a few years old but he basically explained that this sort of thing needs the acts_as_polymorphs gem.

**So the solution was to do the following:**

- I create 6 models, all extending ActiveRecord::Base
- add `has_many_polymorphs` to the post model
- create a polymorphic association called "snippetable" in the snippet model
- add some new fields to the snippets table through my migration file

Here's my code:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many_polymorphs :snippets, :from => [:codes, :texts, :videos, :images], :through => :snippets
end

class Snippet < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :snippetable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Code < ActiveRecord::Base
  # don't have to put anything in here  
end

class Text < ActiveRecord::Base
  # don't have to put anything in here          
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  # don't have to put anything in here  
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  # don't have to put anything in here  
end
```

The only other thing we need, is to stick a few new fields in the CreateSnippets migration:

```
class CreateSnippets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :snippets do |t|
      t.references :post
      t.column :snippetable_id,   :integer, :null => false
      t.column :snippetable_type, :string,  :null => false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And that's it! Unbelievably I can now go to rails console and do the following:

```
p = Post.first
p.codes << Code.create(:code=>"This is a code snippet")
p.images << Image.create(:image=>"xyz.png")
p.images << Image.create(:image=>"123.png")

p.codes.count # returns 1
p.images.count # returns 2
p.snippets.count # returns 3 !!!
```

Yaldi!

Anyway, it's taken me 11 days to fix this, and it REALLY depressed me that I couldn't do it. I hope this helps someone.

Here are some decent reading materials for acts_as_polymorph:

- [jstewart's rails 3 gem](https://github.com/jystewart/has_many_polymorphs)
- [Pratik Nait (of 37 signals) Blog post on it](http://m.onkey.org/has_many_polymorphs-for-dummies)

What a carry on

Answer (score 5):

I kinda like the `type` field, actually. You *could* use the magic of [single table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html), but it's well-known to be a fragile system that, surprise, includes a `type` field, anyway.

And then you could use the [polymorphism](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/howtos/db-relationships/polymorphic) solution, but seems a bit silly to have four different tables to represent almost exactly the same thing.

Honestly, using a simple `type` field and changing the interpretation based on that will probably give you the best results and fewest headaches.

As far as what you'd do in your template goes, that you can probably play by ear. One clean solution might be a simple helper to call like `snippet_content` which, based on the `type` field, will call the helper `snippet_content_text` or `snippet_content_image` or `snippet_content_code` or `snippet_content_video`. Or you can just do the if-then branching in the template, or refer to any number of partial templates (though be careful with that, since those can get slow when used unnecessarily).

Comment: +1 For single table inheritance. However, if these 4 snippets you are talking about are meant to have different attributes, then single table inheritance will become messy as all these attributes need to go in the same table. In that case, polymorphism is a better solution.

Comment: @Chirantan: Nah. I'm talking about just different helper methods that interpret a single text field. I should have made that clear, though, so editing now :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I found it helpful.  I have posted my own answer detailing how I fixed this

Answer (score 2):

1. I like this approach, but I always run into some subtle complications later on.
2. Create the appropriate views (`texts/_text.html.haml`, `images/_image.html.haml`, etc), so you can let Rails handle it for you:

   ```
   = render @post.snippets
   ```
3. Like it or not: the "type"-field is the way to have Rails magic help you create the proper instances.

Update: polymorphic relations work too, let every snippet have their own tables. Is it a **is a** relation or a **behaves like** type of relation? You could say that Images and Texts both behave like snippets. In that case, go for a module named `Snippet` and mix it in.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :snippets, :polymorphic => true
end

class Text < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Snippet
  belongs_to :post, :as => :snippet
end

module Snippet
  # shared behavior here
end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it's taken me a while to figure out how to fix this. I've posted my own answer explaining how I resolved this issue.